# What exactly is edge distribution?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, distribution, edge-detection

I am trying to understand [this paper](http://zpascal.net/cvpr2017/Ma_A-Lamp_Adaptive_Layout-Aware_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf). 
In section 3.1.1, they talk about an image's patch edge distribution and chrominance distribution, defined by a two mean vectors and two covariance matrixes. Yet, I don't really understand to what these values correspond to. For example, if I apply a OpenCv edge distribution algorithm to an image, for instance a Canny Edge detector to a 200x300 image, I will get an 200x300 matrix. In this case, is the mean vector composed of the mean values of each row, and the covariance composed by the covariances between row vectors ? In that case, the covariance matrix would be of size 200x200. Yet, I could do the same column-wise. The shape of the covariance matrix would then be 300x300. How do we choose to proceed column or row wise ? Is this really what they call edge distribution ?

Comment: "if I apply a OpenCv edge distribution algorithm to an image" -- **edge distribution** is not the same as **edge detection**. It's a pitty that the paper doesn't include a reference for this concept, as it's not a standard concept. You could start reading papers listed [by this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=image+%22edge+distribution%22), though I would't hold my breath...

Answer (score 0):

In the paper, the edge distribution is defined as a multivariate Gaussian distribution (they write "multivariant"). You might assume the variables are two-dimensional coordinates.

So what you could do is fit a 2D gaussian distribution on the Canny result. Or go one step back and use the Sobel magnitude. That would more likely fit the intention of the paper.

Edge direction could be a third variable of the distribution, but I wouldn't expect it.